# Chain vim yank and paste?

Tags: vim, neovim

Is it possible to chain yank move and paste? Something like `:10,20y | 30 | p`? Goal is to yank line 10 to 20 and paste at line 30 and the cursor is at line 25 (preferably without the move part to avoid moving the cursor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use `:help :t`?

```
:10,20t30
```

Comment: This is neat! Pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. Is there a way of doing this without moving the cursor though?

Comment: No, that's not how Ex commands work in general. But you can come back to where you come from with "backtick-backtick".

Comment: If `:t` is hard to remember, you can also use `:copy`. `:copy` and `:t` are the same.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with ex commands, specifically the normal command, like so:

```
:10,20yank | normal! 30G | normal! p
```

30G means move to line 30, and pasting can be done with normal! again. I use normal with a ! here so that any bindings you may be using make no impact.

You could also use a register to avoid clobbering the default register,

```
:10,20yank a | normal! 30G | normal! "ap
```

This should work in both neovim and normal vim.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me i get an error saying "E486: Pattern not found:" and the last thing i searched for. Seems to be caused by the | normal! p part

Comment: or rather when doing normal! 30G | normal! p